# Modify the "lastlog" part in the modern motd

Tags: ssh, login, motd

After the small scripts on `/etc/update-motd.d/` are run and, before login runs my shell (if I understood the docs properly) lastlog is somehow run and shown like this:

```
Last login: Wed Oct 18 12:08:39 2017 from xx.xx.xx.xx
```

I'd like to intercept that output to improve it. I was thinking storing the last three IP's to successfully log in or something and make a quick check to see if there's something new I should know.

I'd also like to throw in the number of failed/success accesses, for the same purpose.

It occurs to me I could code it and put it like a `98-ssh-seccheck` thing, but that lastlog line would still show up, pointlessly.

TL;DR: How is that lastlog inserted and how can I intercept/modify it?

Comment: Related:  https://serverfault.com/questions/598043/how-do-i-edit-the-ssh-last-login-message

Comment: Thanks, I read that one too. Given that post is more than 3 years old and neither of the two answers were good, I'm hoping something's changed for the good :)

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/704605/334516?

Comment: Thanks @muru! I think that'll work, cancel the default lastlog and generate my own with more info. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it, otherwisse I'll post it :)

Comment: @CarlesAlcolea sure, you can post it. Maybe add the script you use to generate your info as well?

Comment: @muru I dislike bash a lot but I'll give it my best and add it here